# laravel4 migration failed (pdo exception)

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, laravel, database-migration

I just used artisan migrate to create some table, but I get an error of Type PDO:

```
 [PDOException]                                                                         
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

A php/mysql testscript could connect to the database just fine, but it was another virtualhost and it did not use PDO.

In Laravel4 edited  **app/config/local/database.php** to set the password and database name.

edit in start.php

UPDATE

I hardcoded the password in the PDO connection array and now terminal says there is no database named "database". Clearly it is looking somewhere else for the config, but I have no other config file.

*(Due to following a tutorial about making a "local" directory it was not working for me)As it stands, I have downloaded the stable version and everything is working great.
I am going to delete this post, to keep the forum clean.*

Comment: Does the root use require a password?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have set up your database connection correctly in app/config/database

[Laravel Database Docs](http://laravel.com/docs/database)

Comment: I have no config/database, but config/local/database.php

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are setting up a 'local' environment in start.php
Otherwise Laravel will look for DB config in app/config/database.php

Answer (score 0):

Kindly Check Your **app/config/database.php** file in local host.

1.)Make Sure local Host Data Base **name** is Correct

2.)Make sure local Host Data Base **username** is correct.

3.)Make sure local Host Data Base **password** is correct.

Comment: This should probably be a comment